# Data cant pass into database MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm doing a website using MVC3 with dynamic data that have to put into database. However i cant seem to find out why is it not append into the database after i create.

Here is the Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FYPMvcApplication.Models;
using System.Web.Providers.Entities;

namespace FYPMvcApplication.Controllers
{
public class CreateController : Controller
{
    private bigModel db = new bigModel();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Course course,LearningOut learningout)
    {
        var loc = new LearningOut();
        loc.Outcomes = GetUserOutcomes();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Courses.Add(course);
            db.LearningOut.Add(learningout);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = learningout.LearningOutID });
        }

        return View(loc);
    }

    private IList<LearningOut> GetUserOutcomes()
    {
        var outcomesList = new List<LearningOut>();
        return outcomesList;
    }


    public ActionResult NewOutcomeRow(int id)
    {
        var outcome = new LearningOut { LearningOutID = id };
        return View("partial/NewOutcomeRow", outcome);
    }

}
}
```

Model:

```
public class LearningOut
{
    public int LearningOutID { get; set; }
    public string LearningOutcomes { get; set; }
    public IList<LearningOut> Outcomes { get; set; }

    public string LearningOutcomesText { get; set; }
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
    public bool E { get; set; }
    public bool F { get; set; }
    public bool G { get; set; }
    public bool H { get; set; }
    public bool I { get; set; }
}
```

Model for Course:

```
public class Course
{

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Prerequisite { get; set; }
    public string References { get; set; }


}
```

Create View:

```
  @model FYPMvcApplication.Models.mainModel
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
        var itemIndex = $("#container input.iHidden").length;
        e.preventDefault();
        var newItem = $("<tr><td><input id='" + itemIndex + "' type='hidden' value='' class='iHidden'  name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /><input type='text' id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]'/></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></<td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='" + itemIndex + "' name='[" + itemIndex + "]' /></td></tr>");
        $("#container").append(newItem);
    });
});
 </script>

<h2>Create</h2>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Step 1: Create Coruse & Module</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Step 2: Instructional Outcomes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Step 3: Module Assessment Plan</a></li>
</ul>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div id="tabs-1">

            @* Course Code *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.course.CourseCode)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.course.CourseCode)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.course.CourseCode)
            </div>

            @* Course Name *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.course.CourseName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.course.CourseName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.course.CourseName)
            </div>

            @* Module Code *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.course.ModuleCode)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.course.ModuleCode)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.course.ModuleCode)
            </div>

            @* Module Name *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.course.ModuleName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.course.ModuleName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.course.ModuleName)
            </div>

            @* Year *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.course.Year)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.course.Year)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.course.Year)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.course.Prerequisite)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.course.Prerequisite)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.course.Prerequisite)
            </div>

            <br />

            <div class="editor-field">
                <table id="container">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Learning Outcomes</th>
                        <th>A</th>
                        <th>B</th>
                        <th>C</th>
                        <th>D</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>F</th>
                        <th>G</th>
                        <th>H</th>
                        <th>I</th>
                    </tr>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.learningOut.Outcomes)
                </table>
                <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add New Outcome" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.course.References)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.course.References)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.course.References)
            </div>
        </div>



        <div id="tabs-2">
            - Construction in progress -

        </div>



        <div id="tabs-3">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
</div>
```

Edit.

My EditorTemplate view

```
  @model FYPMvcApplication.Models.mainModel
 @{
Layout = null;
 }
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.learningOut.LearningOutID, new { @class = "iHidden" })
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.LearningOutcomesText) </td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.Outcomes)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.A)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.B)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.C)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.D)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.E)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.F)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.G)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.H)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.learningOut.I) </td>
    </tr>
```

Partial View

```
   @model FYPMvcApplication.Models.mainModel
   @{    Layout = null; }
   <tr>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" id="@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_id" class="iHidden"  name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].id' />
    <input type='text' id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_text'   name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].text' />
</td>
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_A' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].A'/>
    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_B' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].B' />

    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_C' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].C' />

    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_D' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].D' />

    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_E' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].E' />

    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_F' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].F' />

    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_G' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].G' />

    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_H' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].H' />

    <input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='@(Model.learningOut.LearningOutID)_I' name='[@Model.learningOut.LearningOutID].I' />
</td>

 </tr>
```

Here is the problem. My course model seems to be able to appear in my database. but my learningout cant.

Edit:

mainModel View

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 namespace FYPMvcApplication.Models
{
public class mainModel
{
    public Course course { get; set; }
    public LearningOut learningOut { get; set; }
}
}
```

included mainmodel & updated my create view.

Comment: Did you check if you are receiving data into LearningOut object in Create action after POST?

Comment: what comes into `learningout` after `POST` right before `db.SaveChanges()`? Can you chack in debug?

Comment: There is way too much irrelevant code in your question. Please trim this back to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: sorry, im kinda new to MVC3 & programming. how do i do a debug on the POST? @teovankot

Comment: i dont think im reciving any data into learningout object. @SivaGopal

Comment: Set breakpont there :)

Comment: @teovankot there is nothing in the debug. :(

Comment: Where is the actual form element your submitting. If your `Create` view model is `mainModel` then your POST method should be `public ActionResult Create(mainModel model)` but as @TiesonT pointed out you have too much irrelevant code and have omitted the important stuff.

Comment: i suppose you do somehing really wrong with models. You post View that Renders with `EditorTemplate`? Then you should see what comes in             `HttpContext.Request.Params` to your Controller. Anyway i think you should use `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` for all your A,B,C... to render your form correct.

Comment: @StephenMuecke my form submitting is in the create. but in this view, i have 2 models course and learningout inside it. 

what are the important stuff that you need anyway? thanks.

Comment: Include `mainModel` and the view for `Create` showing how you declare the model, the form and just a few of the controls your creating for properties of the model. And delete whats not relevant (for instance, whats `public PartialViewResult Login()` got to do with the issue?)

Comment: @teovankot i have updated it to @html.checkboxfor(). what do you mean by httpcontext.request.params? where do i add that and what does it do? thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the correction. i have updated my question above. hope it helps your understanding. thanks!

Comment: Still too much code here. What is the actual problem. Both parameters `course` and `learningout` in the POST method will be `null` because your model is `mainModel` (and you have not included a `[Bind(Prefix="..")]` attribute)

Comment: in you controller set break point and add to watch `HttpContext.Request.Params` object to see what exactly comes to controller. also you can see it in browser what params posted to controller. @StephenMuecke already say that you messed up with binding, i tell you the way how you can understand what exactly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can change controller as..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(mainModel _mainModel)
{
    var loc = new LearningOut();
    loc.Outcomes = GetUserOutcomes();

    //if (ModelState.IsValid)  Remove this comment if you want to validate
    {
        db.Courses.Add(_mainModel.course);
        db.LearningOut.Add(_mainModel.learningout);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = learningout.LearningOutID });
    }

    return View(loc);
}
```